# What is the name of this old shooting game?

Tags: game-identification

I saw this in a an old movie (the movie has been made about 20 years ago).
Here is a screenshot:

[image]

And [This](https://youtu.be/y7SUNPGggdo?t=33) is a YouTube video from the moment the game has been played in the movie.

Comment: You seem to link to a Youtube video that shows a scene from the game that is what BlueRaja - Danny Pflughoeft found, yet the screenshot is of the game that der derpa found.  So you have two games in question...  Your screenshot is from [this time mark](https://youtu.be/y7SUNPGggdo?t=74), while the link to the video is not.

Comment: Yes I thought the kid is playing the same game! I checked the continuation and luckily he didn't start the third game ;)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's level 1 of [Apocalypse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apocalypse_(video_game)), a PS1 game starring Bruce Willis (!?!)

[image: Apocalypse (PS1)]

Here is a clip of someone playing through that same scene:

---

[Edit] This is the game shown from [0:30 to 0:45](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y7SUNPGggdo&t=33s). But it looks like there's a second game shown, starting at [1:15](https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=74&v=y7SUNPGggdo) - see the other answer for that one.

Comment: I actually believe the other answer is correct.  While this game looks similar, gameplay of the Small Soldiers game looks more like the screenshot.  You can see what looks like a similar structure seen in the screenshot at [this point of the video](https://youtu.be/lJiSg_hs9Hc?t=175), as well as the purple monster guy/thing.

Comment: Actually... there are discrepancies here.  The OP has a screenshot that looks like Small Soliders, but the link to the youtube video shows this game... Oh boy...  See https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/395384/what-is-the-name-of-this-old-shooting-game#comment555250_395384

Comment: @TimmyJim There are two sequence of the movie that contains playing the game. Maybe they changed the game in the second one.

Answer (score 4):

I believe its *Small Soldiers* (the game based on the movie). I had the action figures and loved the game as a kid.

The main indicators for me are the purple guy chained up on the left and the main character is the leader of the Gorgons.

Comment: I actually think this is *a correct answer*, looking at some gameplay video of this game it seems to be more like the screenshot https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lJiSg_hs9Hc.  It appears that there are two games in question actually.

Comment: @derderpa Thanks! Maybe from [this sequence](https://youtu.be/y7SUNPGggdo?t=74) they changed the game?!

Comment: Your welcome, its worth the play if you get your  hands on a copy or  download it